# Maximum number of clients reached?

Tags: proxy, configuration-management

I installed an Ubuntu Server (Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS) with the proxy Squid and Privoxy. Everything worked fine except ... When there are several Windows computers (no matter the Windows version) that connect to my Ubuntu Server via my proxy to go on the Internet (no matter the browser), I have a message in My Windows browser "Maximum number of clients reached". I can no longer access any website.

Could you help me find a solution to this problem please?

Comment: I see as a bug but saw this temporary solution [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=188052) hope it helps

Comment: Thanks George,
I looked at your link and I am under Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS so it does not concern me since I do not have GUI on my Linux.

Comment: So you only experience this issue with a Windows browser? Did you read the section on keep-alive-timeout in the [privoxy manual](https://www.privoxy.org/user-manual/config.html) by any chance?

Comment: You might also find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser) informative.

Comment: Could you provide some details (logs) that might make it clear that this is an issue with your Ubuntu Server rather than limitations with the Windows browsers in question?

Comment: Ok Elder, je vais voir cela...

Comment: Just to say that it does not come from browsers. I used before a proxy software where I had no problem but you are right Elder, it is probably Privoxy that poses a problem, it just needs the well parameterized.